How to use AWS IAM Role in a local ASP .NET website development environment
I have multiple ASP .NET websites running on an AWS Linux 2024 EC2 instance and I want to use AWS Cognito for authentication. In production I believe I will need to create an IAM Role to allow access to Cognito and assign it to the EC2 instance. But first I am trying to get this working locally and I am not sure how to proceed with using an IAM Role in my local development environment.

Theres a bunch of ways of handling IAM credentials - the simplest being creating an IAM User, attaching the same policies as your Role, creating an API key and setting thoe values as environment variables.
If you want to use a role same as PROD, you could look at the AWS CLI command aws sts assume-role command - but you will need the cli installed, and a user setup to allow you to run the assume role command. You can use that to assume the role and recieve temporary creds and put them either in the config file or environmnet variables. This method also allows you to link MFA etc to the user and various other things and you can wrap up the functionality to suit your needs in a simple shell script.
Below example taken is from STS docs

assume a role
The following assume-role command retrieves a set of short-term credentials for the IAM role s3-access-example.

aws sts assume-role \
    --role-arn arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/xaccounts3access \
    --role-session-name s3-access-example


Output:

{
    "AssumedRoleUser": {
        "AssumedRoleId": "AROA3XFRBF535PLBIFPI4:s3-access-example",
        "Arn": "arn:aws:sts::123456789012:assumed-role/xaccounts3access/s3-access-example"
    },
    "Credentials": {
        "SecretAccessKey": "9drTJvcXLB89EXAMPLELB8923FB892xMFI",
        "SessionToken": "AQoXdzELDDY//////////wEaoAK1wvxJY12r2IrDFT2IvAzTCn3zHoZ7YNtpiQLF0MqZye/qwjzP2iEXAMPLEbw/m3hsj8VBTkPORGvr9jM5sgP+w9IZWZnU+LWhmg+a5fDi2oTGUYcdg9uexQ4mtCHIHfi4citgqZTgco40Yqr4lIlo4V2b2Dyauk0eYFNebHtYlFVgAUj+7Indz3LU0aTWk1WKIjHmmMCIoTkyYp/k7kUG7moeEYKSitwQIi6Gjn+nyzM+PtoA3685ixzv0R7i5rjQi0YE0lf1oeie3bDiNHncmzosRM6SFiPzSvp6h/32xQuZsjcypmwsPSDtTPYcs0+YN/8BRi2/IcrxSpnWEXAMPLEXSDFTAQAM6Dl9zR0tXoybnlrZIwMLlMi1Kcgo5OytwU=",
        "Expiration": "2016-03-15T00:05:07Z",
        "AccessKeyId": "ASIAJEXAMPLEXEG2JICEA"
    }
}

Theres also various "mock" ec2 metadata services for replicating services including instance roles and instance metadata for local development environments (I cant recommend one specifically, but i know they exist).
